# Django form unittest with ChoiceField and MultipleChoiceField failing is_valid()

Tags: python, django, forms, unit-testing, choicefield

I'm running into a small problem with writing a unit test for a Django form. I really just want to check the is_valid() method and have seen examples but my code isn't working and after a day or so of reading up on Google I've yet to find the answer I'm looking for.  Below is the code for the forms.py and test_forms.py

## forms.py

```
class DataSelectForm(forms.Form):
    #these are done in the init funct.
    result_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'field-long'}))
    band_selection = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'multiselect field-long'}))
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, result_list=None, band_list=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if result_list is not None and band_list is not None:
            self.fields["result_type"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=result_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'field-long'}))
            self.fields["band_selection"] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'multiselect field-long'}), choices=band_list
```

## test_forms.py

```
 def test_data_select_form(self):
        results = ResultType.objects.all()
        results_value = []
        for result in results:
            results_value.append(result.result_type)
        bands = SatelliteBand.objects.all()
        bands_value = []
        for band in bands:
            bands_value.append(band.band_name)
        form_data = {'result_type': results_value, 'band_selection': bands_value, 'title': 'a title', 'description': 'some description'}
        form = DataSelectForm(data = form_data)

        print(form['title'].value())
        print(form['description'].value())
        print(form['result_type'].value())
        print(form['band_selection'].value())

        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

The only thing I get when I run the test case is "AssertionError: False is not true"  I understand the error, just not why I'm getting it.  I'm passing in all the data and I can see it when I run the print statements.  I've tried taking the result_type and band_selection and passing it into the constructor instead of it being a part of the form_data but that didn't work either.  What am I missing?

Comment: before the assertion statement add ```form.is_valid(); print(form.errors)```

Comment: Also think about minimising your test to the minimum required data to make it work. Instead of bands_value, you could just use ['test band name"]. Then you can delete a heap of lines to setup bands and bands_value. This will make your test faster and easier to read. You can also do the same for results_value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `result_list` and `band_list` when you construct your form.

```
# These aren't the actual choices you want, I'm just showing that
# choices should be a list of 2-tuples.
result_list = [('result1', 'result1'), ('result2', 'result2'), ...]
band_list = [('band1', 'band1'), ('band2', 'band2'), ...]

DataSelectForm(result_list=result_list, band_list=band_list, data=form_data)
```

If you don't pass the values to the form, then you don't set the choices for the fields. If the fields don't have any choices, then the values in the `data` dict cannot be valid, so the form will always be invalid.

Comment: Tried doing it as suggested filling result_list and band_selection with a list of tuples that would be seen on the page but I get this error:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_type'

Comment: It was a typo in my answer, it should be `band_list` and `result_list`, as in your `__init__` method.

Comment: So apparently I had tried passing the information in to the __init__ or as part of the form_data, but never both.  Thank you for clearing that up for me on my end.  Definitely have a more clear understanding of how forms get tested as a result.